# Entity framework and failed updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4 for my project.  I have identity fields as primary keys for some of these entities.

Now if for some reason when I try to insert a new row and SaveChanges() fails then I am assuming that the identity value would still be incremented and there would be a break in the sequence.

My question is what if I am saving a lot of entities in a loop? What happens to the ones that I had added to the context but error out on SaveChanges()....will they cause the identity values to be incremented on each subsequent call to SaveChanges() since those entities were never committed to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SaveChanges fails, you will get an exception and you will not be able to save any more items further because calling SaveChanges again and again will keep on failing to last change that didn't save.

Identity will never break, it is not Entity Framework that manages Identity, it is SQL Server, SQL Server will do its job correctly regardless of failure of Entity Framework.